# Getting different accuracy on each run of Random Forest, Non-Linear SVC and Multinomial NB in python for text classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, text-classification

I am working on a binary text classification problem in python, and have developed models in Random Forest, Non-Linear SVC & Multinomial NB.

But on each run, of these respective models, am getting different accuracy & confusion matrix parameters on the test set. I have used random_state parameter in train_test_split and while initializing each of these models. Random.Seed is also added in the code.

Is there anything else I am missing?

Thanks.

**Code Sample:**

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.15, stratify= Y, random_state = 42) 

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', stop_words = 'english', max_df = 0.8, min_df = 0.05, ngram_range=(1,3)) 
tfidf_train = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train) 
tfidf_test = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(X_test) #Default Hyperparameters 

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(random_state = 42) 

rfc.fit(tfidf_train,Y_train) 
predictions = rfc.predict(tfidf_test) 

score = metrics.accuracy_score(Y_test, predictions) # get scores

print("accuracy: %0.3f" % score) #printing score
```

Comment: Please provide some code example regarding the data split, learner initialization and fits.

Comment: the others too pls i.e. randomforest(....), model.fit(....)

Comment: You have to provide some real code sample in your question. This is the standard way to help yourself to get better(sometimes any) answer to your question on SO.

Comment: Some tools uses `numpy.random.seed()` not `random.random.seed()` for example.

Comment: try to use numpy.random.seed() in your code, their might be some random action in some of the utility you used.

Comment: Well, that worked. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I'm happy about your success, then I post an answer to the future reader, please accept it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the utility you used might be contain some hidden **random action**, uncertainty.

As some of the libraries use [numpy.random()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/routines.random.html) instead of [random.random()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html) you should use `numpy.random.seed()`.